# searching for name using vectors

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, stl-algorithm

how do i search for a name that has been entered by the user from the program? Currently i have this for my search but whenever the program found the selected student, it will print non-stop like a never ending loop. im also using polymorphism for this, as student is categorized into local and international student.

I've thought of using the stl algorithm to iterate through the students but im quite new to stl. I've tried some examples from the internet but it always gave me an error when applied to my program.

main function

```
int main()
{
    clsUniversityProgram objProgram[3];

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        objProgram[x].programInfo();
    }

    vector <clsStudent*> student;
    addStudents(student, objProgram);
    searchStudent(student);
    return 0;
}


void searchStudent(const vector <clsStudent*>& s)
{
    string searchName;
    const clsStudent *foundStudent;

    cout << "\nEnter student name to search for. [ENTER] terminates" << endl;
    cin >> searchName;

    if (s.size() == 0)
        cout << "There is 0 student in the database.";

    while(searchName.length() != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            if (s[i]->getName() == searchName)
            {
                cout << "Found " << searchName << "!";
               // s[i]->print();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "No records for student: " << searchName;
                cout << "\nEnter student name to search for. [ENTER] terminates" << endl;
                cin >> searchName;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: heard of find/find_if? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i search for a name that has been entered by the user from the program?

Using `std::find_if`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(s.begin(), 
                       s.end(),
                       [&searchName](const clsStudent* student)
                       { return student->getName() == searchName; });
if (it != s.end()) {
  // name was found, access element via *it or it->
else {
  // name not found
}
```

C++03 version:

```
struct MatchName
{
  MatchName(const std::string& searchName) : s_(searchName) {}
  bool operator()(const clsStudent* student) const
  {
    return student->getName() == s_;
  }
 private:
  std::string s_;
};


vector<clsStudent*>::iterator it = std::find_if(s.begin(), 
                                                s.end(),
                                                MatchName(searchName));

// as before
```

Comment: [&searchName](const clsStudent* student)
What does this line of code do?

Comment: @AlexiusLim it is a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) which captures `searchName` by reference, and takes a `clsStudent*` as argument.

Comment: auto doesnt seem to work here. my compiler gave me an error saying it does not name a type

Comment: @AlexiusLim Maybe your compiler does not support C++11. There are C++03 alternatives to everything I posted.

Comment: @AlexiusLim I added a C++03 version.

Comment: Having a member `s` and an argument `s` and trying to initialize the former with the latter in the `MatchName` constructor like `s(s)` doesn't seem to be a very good idea.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I agree as far as the name being short and non-descriptive goes. I have no problem with the argument and the member having the same name though. Anyway, I gave the argument a more descriptive name.

Comment: missing ":" after (const std::string& searchName)

Answer (score 0):

Because if the student is found, you print the name, then break the `for`-loop, and when the `while` condition is re-evaluated and is still true because the `searchName` has not changed. You should either set `searchName` to a length 0 string or use some other condition to break out of the `while` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The application continuously prints the result because your condition `while(searchName.length() != 0)` is still valid. When you write `break` you break out of the for loop `for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)`. For example:

```
while (true) {
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "I get printed forever, because while keeps calling this for loop!" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    // Calling break inside the for loop arrives here
    std::cout << "I get printed forever, because while's condition is always true!" << std::endl;
}
```

If you're trying to allow users to continually search the collection of students (i.e. something along the lines of "student found/not found, find another?") you need to include the lines...

```
cout << "\nEnter student name to search for. [ENTER] terminates" << endl;
cin >> searchName;
```

... inside your while loop in order to modify `searchName` and prompt the user that an empty input will result in the program to exit.